# Cannot discover ipad in Develop menu in Mac Safari

Tags: javascript, macos, ipad, debugging, web-inspector

I need to debug a Javascript on iPad Safari (iOS-6). I guess this can be done using remote debugging by connecting it to the Mac (or using a xCode iPad or iPhone simulator instead of connecting an actual iPad). I also need to turn on Safari->Advanced->WebInspector on the iPad and Safari->Preferences-> Advanced ->check the "show Develop menu in the menu bar" option in my macbook. And then when the Develop option appears in the top Safari toolbar (I dont know the exact terminology for this) I should be seeing my iPad there and then can start remote debugging. Now everything is fine except the fact that I cant see the ipad (or the simulator as I tried both option) in the Develop option in Safari. Any ideas/thought what am I missing here?

Comment: Same issue.. I suspect it might be disabled on the windows version of safari. I hope this isn't the case

Answer (score 0):

You must have at least Safari 6+

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you can't on Windows unless you're doing some form of emulation--
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html

"Important: You can only inspect apps on devices that have been transferred to your device from Xcode. You cannot inspect apps that have been downloaded from the App Store, even if it is your app."

You also need OSX 10.7 and safari 6, which doesn't exist for windows yet. :(

Comment: This answer is almost totally irrelevant. The asker was already clear that he's asking about doing this on Mac, not Windows, and the quote you've given relates to using Safari to inspect a `UIWebView` object in an iOS native app, which the OP hasn't given us any reason to think he's doing. The only slightly relevant detail here is that Safari 6 is required (and hence also OSX 10.7, since that is the only OS that supports Safari 6). You could replace this whole answer with "You need Safari 6" and have the same amount of useful or relevant content.